# Autofilter in VBA with criteria as a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I want to use autofilter in vba to filter using a dynamic range of cell values.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$954092").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=???? _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I want to use a dynamic range of cells like

```
Range("A1",Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

Can you suggest how to specify this?

I have tried passing the following to Criteria1:

```
Range(###).Value
Array(Range(###))
```

etc.

Ex.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
----------------------------
 A        1       3       Y
 B        3       3       N
 A        2       2       N
 C        6       1       Y
 B        9       3       Y
```

I want to filter out the rows with values `A` & `C` in `Col1`.

Comment: Filtering on multiple criteria is easier with advanced filter. Take a look e.g. [here](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html)

Comment: Advanced Filter works where there is a specific filter for each column of data. What I need is a filter for a single column with selection of multiple values in that column data.

Comment: actually advanced filter works for that too, try it out. Create a column of data with the same header, following your example `Col1` and underneath it put `A` and `C` in the next rows. Now select advanced filter on your data and in filter criteria put the whole thing, with the column header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @xificurC mentioned, Advanced filter does the trick! I was able to use the following code to filter multiple values at once using just a reference to a range

```
Range("A1:A6").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, 
    CriteriaRange:=Range("A10:A12"), Unique:=False
```

Answer (score 4):

If we use the Recorder on a small **AutoFilter** we see:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1:C20").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$20").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Alice", "Boris", "Mike"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

So **AutoFilter** wants a 1-based array for *Criteria1*

Say the desired list is in sheet *xx* in column **A.**  We will make an array from this list:

```
Sub Macro11()
    Dim N As Long, r As Range
With Sheets("xx")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim ary(1 To N)
        For i = 1 To N
            ary(i) = .Cells(i, 1)
        Next i
End With

    Range("A1:C20").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$20").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define the last row using whatever method you prefer, and then using that value in your function.  Something like:

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Foo"
```

I would strongly advise you to fully qualify your range references to avoid potential headaches down the road, but this should get you started.

Comment: What you say is for the Activesheet.Range
I want to specify it for the Criteria1 parameter where you specified as "Foo"

Comment: @Vamsi well you'd have to tell me that, I can't see your workbook layout.  ActiveSheet is okay to use, as long as you don't have a bunch of other .Select or .Activate statements in your VBA code.  If you do, it's hard to guarantee that you are where you think you are when the filter code is run.